# В js надо записать  градиенты

Tags: javascript

В js надо записать  градиенты, но надо же поставить приставки -o-, -moz- и т.п. Как облегчить это?

```
  User_status.grad.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%)'
User_status.grad.style.backgroundImage = '-o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%)'
User_status.grad.style.backgroundImage = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%)'
User_status.grad.style.backgroundImage = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%)'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var array_prefix = ['-webkit', '-o', '-ms', '-moz'];

for(var i=0; i < array_prefix.length; i++) {
   User_status.grad.style.backgroundImage = array_prefix[i]+'-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%)'
}
```

и обернуть всё в функцию.